# How to count all possible convertions to limited string size?

Tags: permutations

I have a string `1111` and I know that `1` can be converted to `1`, `10` or `100` but the string will be still 4 symbols length, so actually each `0` sign replaces next symbol.

So it could be

```
1111

1110
1101
1011

1010

1001
1100
```

How to count all possible convertions to limited string size?

I counted that:

```
first symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10` or `100`. 

second symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10`or `100`. 

third symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10`. 

fourth symbol `1` could be converted to `1`.
```

So I have some map of size of convertions for each position:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 3
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
```

And with that map I know that there are 3 permutations with `10` , 2 permutations with `100` and 1 permutation with `1`, but I can't catch mix of permutations.

Like if there were 5 initial symbols `11111` and the same convertions, so I didn't catch mixes like

```
10100
10010

10101
10110
11010
```

How to catch them?

But I can't solve it in this direction.

Can you help me with that?

Firstly, how to do it using my map of convertions.

And if it is a dead end, then how to do it with other solutions?

***UPD***
Trying to rephrase it.

I have an alphabet `{1, 10, 100}` and I need to count all possible permutations that are limited to the total symbol length of 4.

How to do it with knowing amount of permutations for each symbol ?
Like

```
first symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10` or `100`. 

second symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10`or `100`. 

third symbol `1` could be converted to `1`, `10`. 

fourth symbol `1` could be converted to `1`.
```

Comment: This is pretty hard to follow.  Can you rephrase it somehow, supplying context.  Is there, for example, a simpler problem of the same type that you _do_ know how to solve?

Comment: @kimchilover, hi, I added UPD section in my post, please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean, how many strings of length $n$ can be formed by freely concatenating 1, 10, and 100, the answer is, the coefficient of $t^n$ in the power series for $$\begin{align*}Z(t)&=\frac1 {1-(t+t^2+t^3)}\\&=1+t+2t^2+4t^3+7t^4+13t^5\cdots.\end{align*}$$
This can be seen by noting that any legal concatenation is either the empty string, the string 1 followed any legal concatenation, the string 10 followed by any legal concatenation, or the string 100 followed by any legal concatenation, leading to the equation 
$$\begin{align*}Z(t)&=1+tZ(t)+t^2Z(t)+t^3Z(t)\\&=1+(t+t^2+t^3)Z(t)\end{align*},$$ whose solution is above.

Note also that in this case each legal concatenation is uniquely parseable: the language $\{1,10,100\}^*$ is uniquely decodable, this means that to count legal concatenations is to count distinct parsings.  Unlike what happens with $\{1,11\}^*$, say, where strings such as 111 have multiple parsings.  See discussions of the [Chomsky–Schützenberger theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem) for further theory, or pp. 36-38 of Shannon and Weaver, [*The mathematical theory of communication*](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_2383164/component/file_2383163/content) for a similar example.

Similarly, the number of strings of length $n$ which can be formed by 
freely
concatenating 1 and 10, the answer is the coefficient of $t^n$ in the power series expansion of $$\begin{align*}Z(t)&=\frac{1}{1-(t+t^2)}\\&= 1+t+2t^2+3t^3+5t^4+8t^5+\cdots\end{align*}$$ and so on.

Comment: So the answer is - the coefficient of ```{t^4}``` in the first formula? But what if length will be still the same = 4, but alphabet will be ```{1, 10}```? The answer should be 5, but the coefficient of ```{t^4}``` in the first formula - is ```7```.

Comment: Change the problem and $Z(t)$ changes too, of course.  See my edited answer.  By the way, what does "convetions" mean?